# Finding groups of values from two colums which have entries in common using SQLite

Tags: sqlite, grouping

I have a table with three columns eg:

```
EID   #   Node1   #   Node 2
----------------------------
50    #    23     #    25
34    #    6      #    11
78    #    25     #    9 
45    #    2      #    45
39    #    12     #     9
40    #    6      #     2
```

EID 50 78 39 Belong together because they share nodes (Connected via nodes 25 9).
EID 34 40 Belong together because they share nodes (Connected via node 6).
EID 45 is alone because it does not share any nodes wit any other EID.
The new table should look like this:

```
CF   #   EIDs       #
---------------------
1    #    50 78 39  #
2    #    34 40     #
3    #    45        #
```

My general question is: Is there a way to do this in SQLite, or should I do this kind of sorting "outside" of the DB using some other program routine?

Comment: This would require recursive common table expressions, which are not yet supported in the current SQLite version.

Comment: If you would post it as an answer I could accept it and could close the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is, it is not possible in SQLite as CL mentioned. Thanks. A TCL solution to the problem is posted at [Grouping dictionary keys whos values (sublist) have entries in common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467991/grouping-dictionary-keys-whos-values-sublist-have-entries-in-common/21475003?noredirect=1#comment32423590_21475003) by Hoodiecrow. Thanks to him for that!