# Grouping dictionary keys whos values (sublist) have entries in common

Tags: dictionary, tcl, grouping

Referring to this problem [Finding groups of values from two colums which have entries in common using SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466271/finding-groups-of-values-from-two-colums-which-have-entries-in-common-using-sqli?noredirect=1#comment32397447_21466271)

I gave it a try in TCL, but I got lost in the loops somewhere:

```
set MyList [ list 50 { 23 25 } 34 { 6 11 } 78 { 25 9 } 45 { 2 45 } 39 { 12 9 } 40 { 6 2 }]

set AllGroups [list]

 dict for {k v} $MyList {
   set Group $k       
   foreach {N1 N2} $v {break}

            dict for {k2 v2} $MyList {
                  foreach {N1_2 N2_2} $v2 {break}
                  if { $N1 == $N1_2 } {                   
                      append Group $k2
                    }
                 if { $N1 == $N2_2 } {                   
                     append Group $k2
                   }    
          }
    lappend AllGroups $Group
}
```

The output is:

**50** 3440 **78** 4540 **39** 4040

which looks like a promising start to a solution. I think the loop looks correct, where is my mistake? Any help is appreciated. Maybe I should use structs instead?

Comment: You're constructing the connected subgraphs of a graph?

Comment: This is a heads-up that my answer has been changed. There was a flaw in the implementation that allowed discontinuities that fragmented some connected subgraphs.  It didn't show up with your data, but when I added some more rows with disconnected EIDs, _*bam*_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem looks simple but is actually surprisingly hard to get right. Hence, the rather long solution. This particular problem has been studied a lot and algorithms can be found on the web, but of course I had to do it the hard way and come up with my own implementation. This means that while it works correctly for the data I've tried it with, it may be inefficient and may still contain bugs. I think it'd be fair to say that its a rather "naive" solution, in the CS sense of the word.

(It doesn't help that while researching for this solution, I found that I'm way out of touch with current computer science terminology (I haven't really been into CS for over twenty years). I picked up the term "maximal common subgraph" to describe what I was searching for, but now it seems that's actually something subtly different. Ah well, as I said I gave up trying to use an established algorithm and rolled my own anyway.)

The problem has a set of *EIDs* (CS-speak: *vertices*) that each have two *nodes*; nodes shared between EIDs form a *direct connection* (*edge*) between them, and the object is to find *bunches* (CS-speak: **not** *cliques*, probably not *maximal common subgraphs*, possibly *transitive closures*) of EIDs that have direct and indirect connections.

To make the solution tractable, I split the process into steps:

1. find the list of connections (where each connection is either a list
   of two or more EIDs connected through a shared node, or else a
   single, unconnected, EID)
2. build a dictionary of connections where
   the keys are EIDs and the values are lists of EIDs that they appear
   in direct connections with (through one or more nodes) -- note that 
   some of the value lists at this point may already *be* the bunch 
   of that EID, while most are just subsets of such bunches.
3. finally, build
   a dictionary where the keys are monotonically increasing
   integers (i.e. I numbered the items) and the values are lists of
   EIDs forming "bunches".

I describe each step a bit further next to the command that performs it.

```
proc main table {
    # This command puts all the processing steps together. The table 
    # is set up at the bottom of the page.

    puts [set data [makedatadictionary $table]]

    puts [set connections [findconnections $data]]

    puts [set connectionsdict \
        [makeconnectionsdict [dict keys $data] $connections]]

    set bunchdict [makebunchdict $connectionsdict]

    puts "\nCF EIDs\n-----------"
    dict for {cf EIDs} $bunchdict {
        puts "$cf  $EIDs"
    }
}
```

This is the command that constructs the bunch dictionary. It processes each key in the input dictionary and collects the EIDs directly or indirectly connected to it by recursively looking at each one of the EIDs in its value list. A (very very obvious) pitfall here is that every EID in a subgraph will produce the same list of collected EIDs (though likely in different sorting orders), so we have to check if the subgraph isn't already in the dictionary before we add it.

```
proc makebunchdict connectionsdict {
    # Given a connections dictionary containing EID keys and EID 
    # tokens representing directly connected EIDs, this command 
    # picks out bunches of EIDs, directly or indirectly connected.
    set result [dict create]
    set n 0
    dict for {key -} $connectionsdict {
        set collected [list]

        recursivelycollect $key $connectionsdict collected

        set collected [lsort $collected]
        if {$collected ni [dict values $result]} {
            dict set result [incr n] $collected
        }
    }
    set result
}
```

This is the command that recursively visits each EID key. It stops when every EID it finds is already in the list of collected EIDs.

```
proc recursivelycollect {key connectionsdict varName} {
    # Recursively visits every EID in a directly connected 
    # group, saving unique EIDs in a variable that lives in 
    # the original caller's stack frame.
    upvar 1 $varName collected
    lappend collected $key
    foreach n [dict get $connectionsdict $key] {
        if {$n ni $collected} {
            recursivelycollect $n $connectionsdict collected
        }
    }
}
```

This is the command that sets up a dictionary of connections. It's fairly straightforward: for every key it builds a list that is the list union of all lists where the key appears. It then reduces each resulting list to unique members.

```
proc makeconnectionsdict {keys connections} {
    # Given a set of keys which are EID tokens, and a list of lists 
    # containing directly connected EIDs, this command constructs a 
    # dictionary with the EID tokens as keys and the lists of every 
    # direct connection set that the EID appears in as values. Note 
    # that it's very likely that
    #   [dict values $connections] != [dict values $result]
    # since the list of connections has lists of EIDs connected by a
    # single node, while the result list here has EIDs connected by 
    # one or more nodes.
    set result [dict create]
    foreach key $keys {
        foreach connection $connections {
            if {$key in $connection} {
                dict lappend result $key {*}$connection
            }
        }
        dict set result $key [lsort -unique [dict get $result $key]]
    }
    set result
}
```

This is the command that finds out which EIDs are connected to each other. It's *very* straightforward: it's basically just an inversion of the input dictionary. I remove the most obvious duplicates at the end.

```
proc findconnections data {
    # This command discovers direct connections between keys in the 
    # dictionary which is passed to it. A direct connection exists 
    # between two keys if they share any members of their value lists. 
    # E.g. 
    #   a {b c}  and  d {e c}  are directly connected, but
    #   a {b c}  and  f {g h}  are not.
    #
    # The result is a list of lists, where each sublist either contains 
    #  * two or more keys: these keys are connected to each other by a 
    #    single value list member, or
    #  * a single key: these keys have no connections at all.
    set result [dict create]
    dict for {key value} $data {
        foreach val $value {
            dict lappend result $val $key
        }
    }
    # Return only the values from the result dictionary, and only 
    # trivially unique values at that.
    lsort -unique [dict values $result]
}
```

This is the command that trivially converts a EID/node/node data table to a dictionary. It's just a convenience command to let me define the input in a more workable format.

```
proc makedatadictionary table {
    # Convert a N x 3 table to a dictionary of N items where 
    # the key is the value in column 1 and its value is the 
    # list of the values in column 2 and 3.
    set data [dict create]
    foreach {col1 col2 col3} $table {
        dict set data $col1 [list $col2 $col3]
    }
    set data
}
```

This is how you get it started. The argument consists of data that represents EID tokens in the first column and node numbers in the second and third columns. The actual values don't affect the workings of this code, but none of the values should be lists.

(In this example, the EIDs 50 -- 40 come from the OP and are presumably real-life data, the rest were made up by me to test the solution.)

```
main {
    50  23  25
    34   6  11
    78  25   9
    45   2  45
    39  12   9
    40   6   2
    99   1   3
    98   4   5
    97   4   7
}
```

(Note: the 'Hoodiecrow' mentioned in the comments is me, I used that nick earlier.)

Comment: Thank for the tricky work. I'll test it thoroughly the coming week and come back to you if I find anything. What are the names of these algorithms you are thinking about?  I did read about NP in wiki, but its more confusing than helping.. Tack en gång till.

Comment: @Lumpi: I started on a list of links to papers describing solutions, but now I'm not even sure they're relevant. AFAICT, a good starting point should be the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm), though it seems it would have to be modified to find _all_ subgraphs. Regarding NP, it doesn't really help, the label "NP complete" is mostly CS-speak for "here be dragons".

Comment: Poor wording there: the FW algorithm of course finds (or at least processes) all subgraphs, it just doesn't _return_ them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand your question correctly, but this might help. I basically used the "nodes" (SQLite problem mentioned in your post) as array keys and append all EIDs to the array element denominated by the "node" -> [list EID1 {node1 node2} EID2 {node3 node4}] etc.

```
set l [ list 50 { 23 25 } 34 { 6 11 } 78 { 25 9 } 45 { 2 45 } 39 { 12 9 } 40 { 6 2 }]
puts $l
foreach {item nodes} $l {
    foreach node $nodes {
        lappend n($node) $item
    }
}
foreach {group items} [array get n] {
    puts "Group: $group Items: $items"
}

50 { 23 25 } 34 { 6 11 } 78 { 25 9 } 45 { 2 45 } 39 { 12 9 } 40 { 6 2 }
Group: 45 Items: 45
Group: 9 Items: 78 39
Group: 23 Items: 50
Group: 2 Items: 45 40
Group: 11 Items: 34
Group: 6 Items: 34 40
Group: 12 Items: 39
Group: 25 Items: 50 78
```